# How to insert sequence.nextval value in Codeigniter active records?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle10g

This is a particular Oracle query:-

```
INSERT INTO tbl_admin 
      (admin_id, admin_username, admin_email, 
      admin_password, admin_fname, admin_lname, admin_type) 
VALUES 
      ('TBL_ADMIN_SEQUENCE.nextval', 'saswat2', 'saswat2@gmail.com',
      '$2a$16$y61NYSwQXSRA4m4GoRWJ5OhthFzfZ9e6yp8QcVhBNgSQK16Q.VkXq', 'Saswat', 'Routroy', 0);
```

Now, to run this quesry using Codeigniter active records, I am writing this code:-

```
    $data = array(
        $this->identifier_field => 'TBL_ADMIN_SEQUENCE.nextval',
        $this->username_field => $username,
        $this->email_field => $email,
        $this->password_field => $password,
        $this->first_name_field => $first_name,
        $this->last_name_field => $last_name,
        $this->type_field => intval($type),
    );

    // If inserting data fails
    if ( ! $this->oracleDB->insert($this->user_table, $data))
    {
        // Return false
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Now, this is giving me an error:-
[image]

How can I fix this? I know I can write the query using `->query()` function, but I want to do it using active records.

Note:- I am using Oracle 10g express edition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->set('status', $status);
$this->db->set('ID', "SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL", FALSE); //false escape
$this->db->insert('mytable');
```

Comment: While this is an answer to the question, it's better to actually describe in a few lines of text what this code is supposed to do.